# Can the healthkit data leave the iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, healthkit

Am creating a health related app.
Using healthkit, i can access user health information.
But can i extract the lab data and process it on the server side?

Can we send iOS healthkit data through api server and process data on server side?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/protecting_user_privacy 
Please read the privacy policy to see if there are any restrictions.

Comment: I don't really think this is a question that can be answered here. This is really a question for a lawyer and something you need to consider in terms of various privacy laws around the world as well as your own potential liability. I don't believe that Apple forbids it as long as the user grants you permission. There are lots of apps that share some health data (mostly less sensitive data like workouts share to a timeline so your friends can see what you have been doing). Sharing a persons weight or heart rate might be problematic.

Comment: Even if you are just processing the data and not sharing it you need to consider the impact of a data breach

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread, some responses from Apple's team

> "The short answer is no. The nature of health information is very personal, so we want to keep it as private as possible. This is taken from the HealthKit Framework Documentation:
> "The HealthKit data is only kept locally on the user’s device. For security, the HealthKit store is encrypted when the device is not unlocked. The HealthKit store can only be accessed by an authorized app. You cannot access HealthKit from extensions (like the Today view) or from a WatchKit app."
> Here's a link to the rest of the documentation, I recommend reading through the HealthKit and Privacy section for some more detail.
> Hope that Helps!"

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/11860